How to get icecat data in multiple languages
Magento 2.4.6
I am using https://packagist.org/packages/icecat/magento2-extension to get data from icecat. Unfortunately, I am only getting data in one language (german) ... is there a way to get data in different languages for my other store views (french, spanish and italian)? Did find no setting in the extension to define languages. The extension settings are not available on store view level.
Thanks for any ideas :)
